# Plotting a multi-index dataframe with Altair

Tags: pandas, bar-chart, altair

I have a dataframe which looks like:

```
data = {'ColA': {('A', 'A-1'): 0,
                 ('A', 'A-2'): 1,
                 ('A', 'A-3'): 1,
                 ('B', 'B-1'): 2,
                 ('B', 'B-2'): 2,
                 ('B', 'B-3'): 0,
                 ('C', 'C-1'): 1,
                 ('C', 'C-2'): 2,
                 ('C', 'C-3'): 2,
                 ('C', 'C-4'): 3},
        'ColB': {('A', 'A-1'): 3,
                 ('A', 'A-2'): 1,
                 ('A', 'A-3'): 1,
                 ('B', 'B-1'): 0,
                 ('B', 'B-2'): 2,
                 ('B', 'B-3'): 2,
                 ('C', 'C-1'): 2,
                 ('C', 'C-2'): 0,
                 ('C', 'C-3'): 3,
                 ('C', 'C-4'): 1}}

df = pd.DataFrame( data )
```

The values for every column are either 0, 1, 2, or 3. These values could just as easily be 'U', 'Q', 'R', or 'Z' ... i.e. there is nothing inherently numeric about them.

I would like to use [Altair](https://altair-viz.github.io/index.html)

** First Set of Charts

I would like to get one bar chart per column.

The labels for the X-axis should be based on the unique values in the columns. The Y-axis should be the count of the unique values in the column.

** Second Set of Charts

Similar to the first set, I would like to get one bar chart per row.

The labels for the X-axis should be based on the unique values in the row. The Y-axis should be the count of the unique values in the row.

This should be easy, but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of Altair's APIs are column-based, and ignore indices unless you explicitly include them (see [Including Index Data](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html#including-index-data) in Altair's documentation).

For the first set of charts (one bar chart per column) you can do this:

```py
alt.Chart(df.reset_index()).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X(alt.repeat(), type='nominal'),
    y='count()'
).repeat(['ColA', 'ColB'])
```

[image]

For the second set of charts (one bar chart per row) you can do something like this:

```py
df_transposed = df.reset_index(0, drop=True).T
alt.Chart(df_transposed).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X(alt.repeat(), type='nominal'),
    y='count()'
).repeat(list(df_transposed.columns), columns=5)
```

[image]

Though this is a bit of a strange visualization, so I suspect I'm misunderstanding what you're after... your data has ten rows, so one chart per row is ten charts.

Comment: Thanks. For the real data, the second visualization make more sense.